# Dynamic Regex for number range using c#

Tags: c#, regex, dynamic

I'm looking at UK postcodes and trying to work out how I can take data from a database `(the first part of a UK postcode)` and dynamically create a regexp for them using c#. For example:

```
AB44-56
```

I know what I want as an output:

```
AB([4][4-9]|[5][0-6])+
```

However, I can't work out how I might be able to do this with logic, perhaps I need to split the Letters from the numbers first, but i can't do that using split.

I have other combinations too - single range:

```
AB31 would be AB[3][1]+
```

Some with just letters:

```
BT would be BT+
```

Some with a single letter and 1 or two numbers:

```
G83 Would be G[8][3]
```

Any suggestions or guidance would be very much appriciated how this may be coded.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand the logic behind what you're going for. Maybe it's the whole **based on my rule** part that's throwing me off, my esp is lacking today.

Comment: Given that you have a very well defined input, it may be less complex just to write a business rule to validate the input by inspecting components of the string rather than dynamically building the RegEx.  RegEx is useful to easily validate input patterns.  You lose that ease in this case.

Comment: What is your "rule" that you want to base your regex on?

Comment: The "rule" here means converting "BT" to "BT+" and converting "AB44-56" to "AB([4][4-9]|[5][0-6])+" for example.  However, the use of `+` is incorrect, since it means "one or more"; in this way the regexes above would also match "AB44484953" or "BTTTTTTTTTT", which are invalid postcodes.

Comment: I don't care what characters are after my regex hence why i put + i only care about the first part, so if someone enter ab46dyyfhydf it would still match

Comment: To explain why i'm doing this, a delivery company defines certain postcodes a specific charge rate, when the user enters their postcode i need to work out what rate they'll be charged based on the first part of their postcode and let them know. I could put in all combinations into the db however i thought setting the ranges for these postcodes i could then dynamically create regexps for them so there is less to run though and it would be more efficient

Comment: "I don't care what characters are after my regex" - In that case, use `.*` (which matches all characters, other than newline) instead of `+` (which matches the previous character or group 1 or more times).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

afrom wikipedia UK postal codes :

> This can be generalised as: (one or two letters)(number between 0 and
>   99)(zero or one letter)(space)(single digit)(two letters)

so

```
^[A-Z,a-z]{0,2}\d+[A-Z,a-z]?\s\d[A-Z,a-z]{2}$
```

might work.

EDIT: Also if you are trying to restric the postal codes to say those with the same prefix as the ones in the database you could do this.

```
var source = "BTasdfweasdf"; //from the database
var input = "BT1A 1BB"; //from the somewhere else
var regex = Regex.Replace(source, @"(^[A-z,a-z]{0,2})(.*)", @"$1\d+[A-Z,a-z]?\s\d[A-Z,a-z]{2}$");
var match = Regex.Match(input,regex);
```